# SSL web application other than Port 443

Tags: 2016, ssl

I want to host two different web application in SP 2016 Farm.
below is requirement and example

- https://www.company1.com (port 443)
- https://www.company2.com

for this requirement is 2nd web application will work with https if I select different port other than 443

two web applications have different SSL certificates because domain names are different.

also here I want to browse two web applications without port number
1st web application I created on port 443 - I can browse web application without using port number in URL

2nd web application I created on Port 4443 - this one how can I configure to browse this web application without URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing preventing you from using SNI so you can have two different certs bound to the same IP:Port combination. Or alternatively, add a second IP to the server and make one site bound to one IP, and the other to the second IP.

Comment: Hi thanks for reply i updated my question' 2nd web application I created on Port 4443 - this one how can I configure to browse this web application without URL?'